# Jquery Chosen get the Id of un-selected value in dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

I have manage to get id of selected option for the [Chosen plugin](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/options.html). Here is the [jsfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Kami924/S4tQf/13/).

Now I am not sure how to get the Id of unselected option. I am using this code to get the id of selected option.

```
 var SelectedIds = $(this).find('option:selected').map(function() {
      if ($(this).attr('value') == params.selected)
        return $(this).prop('id')

    }).get();
    alert(SelectedIds);
```

Comment: You want to get id of all unselected options after any number of options selected right?

Comment: @itzmukeshy7 . Basically I want the Id of only the currently un-selected option. E.g If the country United State is selected in the dropdown. When the user unselect United State. I want to get its Id. Same goes of any other country.

Comment: When user unselects any selected options you want to do some function here right?

Comment: @itzmukeshy7 Yes!! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When an option is deselected, you get the change event, but the `params` object has a `deselected` property that you can use just like you're using the `selected`.

I made a jsfiddle for you to demonstrate:  http://jsfiddle.net/1eut1c3d/

```
$("#chosen").chosen().on('change', function(evt, params) {

  if (params.selected !== undefined) {
     var selectedID = $(this).find('option:selected').map(function() {
        if ($(this).attr('value') == params.selected)
        return $(this).prop('id')
   }).get();
   alert("Selected: " + selectedID);
}
if (params.deselected !== undefined) {
    var deselectedID =   $(this).find('option').not(':selected').map(function() {
      if ($(this).attr('value') == params.deselected)
        return $(this).prop('id')  
       }).get();
       alert("Deselected: " + deselectedID);
    }
});
```

Comment: so `.not(':selected')` was the key element I was missing ..Thanks

Comment: You're welcome.  You don't actually need that part because you can just do `$(this).find('option').map(...)` and it will find all of the options, but adding `.not(':selected')` filters it down a bit and makes it find it faster, I think.